Is there a standard approach to measure T2 time?
I saw that different ion trap quantum computer manufacturers have given their own T2 (dephasing) times, but it is not clear whether they are obtained by the same test steps.
My question is: Is there a standard procedure how to measure T2 time?

Depending on the kind of T2, you can do a Ramsey experiment or a spin echo experiment: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/2451/1939
